# Search full document in mongodb for a match

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there a way to match a value with every array and sub document inside the document in mongodb collection and return the document

```
{
  "_id" : "2000001956",
  "trimline1" : "abc",
  "trimline2" : "xyz",
  "subtitle"  : "www",
  "image" : {
    "large" : 0,
    "small" : 0,
    "tiled" : 0,
    "cropped" : false
  },     
  "Kytrr" : {
      "count" : 0,
      "assigned" : 0
  }
```

}

for eg if in the above document I am searching for xyz or "ab" or "xy" or "z" or "0" this document should be returned.

I actually have to achieve this at the back end using C# driver but a mongo query would also help greatly.

Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: You need to match document, if any of its field or field of subdocument or field of subdocument inside an array contains the given string?

Comment: may be this will explain it better.. on the client side we are doing an angular $.search and I want to achieve the same thing on the backend. return document that has that value anywhere in the document excluding field names.

Comment: Ok, but it is not a good architecture. Better define fields you want to search in. So you can create indexes with that fields. Without indexes your back-end become unresponsible in case of big amount of documents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While Malcolm's answer above would work, when your collection gets large or you have high traffic, you'll see this fall over pretty quickly. This is because of 2 things. First, dropping down to javascript is a big deal and second, this will always be a full table scan because $where can't use an index.

MongoDB 2.6 introduced text indexing which is on by default (it was in beta in 2.4). With it, you can have a full text index on all the fields in the document. The [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/#index-all-fields) gives the following example where a text index is created for every field and names the index "TextIndex".

```
db.collection.ensureIndex(
    { "$**": "text" },
    { name: "TextIndex" }
)
```

Comment: I have created the index. How do I use it in the query?

Comment: Link to the documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/

Comment: Linking the documentations is the correct approach, but in case someone else had enough and just wants the answer:
`db.collection.find( { $text: { $search: "xyz" } } )`

Comment: Please keep in mind that mongo indexes are very costly for memory especially this one.

Answer (score 18):

You could probably do this using '$where'

```
db.mycollection({$where:"JSON.stringify(this).indexOf('xyz')!=-1"})
```

I'm converting the whole record to a big string and then searching to see if your element is in the resulting string. Probably won't work if your xyz is in the fieldnames!

You can make it iterate through the fields to make a big string and then search it though.

This isn't the most elegant way and will involve a full tablescan. It will be faster if you look through the individual fields!

Comment: I have implemented this solution. It seems to be working fine and its not slowing down the app :)  
Thank you!

Comment: Great! I tried to work with text indexes for a while but found this solution is much more flexible and easy to implement.

Comment: Kudos! Very nice. I use this for manual research.